# write text inside div element use webbrowser vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Need to write in element .

This is the HTML code

```
< div id="t" class="message-tools__textarea js-scroller" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Write a message (Enter to send)">XXXXXX< /div>
```

My question is how to write text like `XXXXXX` ?????

Comment: This does not give us an idea of what are you trying to achieve. Are you compiling the <div ...>xxxx</> code, or do you need to REPLACE some text (XXXX)? If you need to replace the text, is it a constant string, variable? A solution depends on the questions above dramatically.

Comment: yes i want REPLACE  text (XXXX) . to be (ZZZZ)

Comment: Oak_3260548 ok now ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
<div id="t" runat="server" ...
```

And then in your codebehind:

```
t.InnerText = "XXXXXXX" ' or t.InnerHTML if you're adding HTML code).
```

Comment: I do not understand you I want to complete the existing code in the web page text Replace

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but I'll explain mine. By making the div a server-side div, you can edit various aspects of it using VB.net code. Since you posted using the VB.net tag, I assumed that's what you're trying to do and showed you how to do so using VB.net.

Answer (score 2):

So, if the text to be replaced is **fixed** and has **only 1 instance** within the HTML code, it should be rather simple:

```
Dim OrigCode, ModifiedCode as string
OrigCode = GetGoogleCodeFromURL  ' get the code
ModifiedCode = OrigCode.Replace("XXXXXXX","ZZZZZZ")

Dim MyHTML as string = "<head>...</head><body><h1>Hello World!</h1><p>&nbsp;</p>" & _
                           ModifiedCode & "<p>&nbsp;</p><p>That's it.</p>"
```

But usually, things are a bit more complicated, so I'm not sure, if you expressed your wish precisely. Also, if the code is big and action is recursive, it might be better to break it into parts and handle only relevant part of it, due to performance issues.

Comment: the code in web page (html code) i want replace it in page not in out page    and i know how replace text inside project . again i want it inside web page and thank you pro

Comment: I'm afraid, we cannot help you, if you don't define your questions clearly. Sorry if it is my English, but I have trouble to understand your question and comments. From my point of view, you are re-defining your question, making it another issue and probably also shifting from VB.NET issue to ASP.NET question? I think you still didn't even define how is your code stored. Is it a file on your local server? Is it a page displayed in your project in webbrowser component via remote URL? Etc.

Comment: My friend I can explain in detail Do I agree to help me?

Comment: From the beginning . I offer Google search page I want to write in the box assigned to write in the site do not forget the Google site for compensation before the Supreme code g Let's go back to the topic
<Div id = "t" class = "message-tools__textarea js-scroller" contenteditable = "true" data-placeholder = "Write a message (Enter to send)"> XXXXXX </ div>
I want the way in which I can by writing(XXXXX) In the page displayed in front of me instead of manually written notes that I wrote a last resort(XXXXX) Manually

Comment: I'm still not sure, if I understand it correctly. And I cannot promise to help, because it might turn to be a question not related to VB.NET. My understanding is, that you get a code from google and place it into your web page. Then you should be able to put the google's code into a variable, handle it as per my answer and finally place modified code into your page... But I have trouble to understand you, sorry.

Comment: you cant answer ok !